# Benefits of 'set foldmethod=marker', but stop 'zf' from adding markers

Tags: folding

If my file already has

```
{{{
  fold contents here
  ...
}}}
```

blocks I want them to be automatically folded when I run `za`; but
I want the ability to create a manual fold using `zf%`, say on just

```
{

  fold contents here
  ....

}
```

without vim automatically modifying my file to

```
{/*{{{*/

fold contents here
...

}/*}}}*/
```

I thought that

```
:help fold-create-marker
```

might be relevant, but I do not understand it.

I have a workaround, but would like a cleaner solution.

`.vimrc` workaround:

```
map <Leader>Zf :set fdm=marker<CR>za:set fdm=manual<CR>za|"create marker method fold, but return to manual fold method
" Above intended for case where '{{{' preexists on currentline, and matching '}}}' exists on subsequent line
```

Comment: Default behavior: add 'foldmarker' surrounded by 'commentstring'
:he foldmarker ->  string (default: "{{{,}}}")
:he commentstring -> string (default "/*%s*/")
'commentstring' is used if it isn't empty.

Answer (score 3):

You could do a global match on all fold markers to create manual folds.

```
:g/{{{/normal! $Nzf%
```

This assumes that {} braces are balanced inside the fold markers, but if you use the "matchit" plugin distributed with Vim, you can make this better with:

```
:let b:match_words = '{{{:}}}'
```

It also assumes that there's only one opening fold marker per line, but I don't see a good way to remove that assumption short of custom scripting.